# How does one send arguments to an embedded Flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

As instructed [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web#embedding-a-flutter-app-into-an-html-page), one can embed a Flutter web app into a web page by wrapping it into an **iframe** element, such as:

```
<iframe src="URL"></iframe>
```

where the URL points to the html of the Flutter web app.

Now, what if you wanted to pre-configure the Flutter web app depending on the context - make it aware of some external value present in the embedder (the iframe HTML element or the parent web page / window).

Is there perhaps a solution where you could instruct Flutter to read a data attribute from the iframe? For example:

```
<iframe src="URL" data-answer="42"></iframe>
```

Any alternatives?

(A broader question would be two-way communication between the embeddable and the embedder.)

Answer (score 3):

Managed to find one way of sending arguments. One can basically put URL query parameters on the src URL of the iframe, like this:

```
<iframe src="https://foo.bar?answer=42"></iframe>
```

To get the query parameters within the Flutter web app you'd then:

```
// Use a dependency on package:universal_html/html.dart
final Map<String, String> params = Uri.parse(html.window.location.href).queryParameters;
final String answer = params['answer']; // -> and there you have the "42".
```